# Sobrescrever uma propriedade da Herança ou não ?Kotlin

Tags: java, android, orientação-a-objetos, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Estou com uma dúvida sobre código :

```
class SaldoInsuficienteException(mensagem:String = "O saldo é Insuficiente") : Exception(mensagem)
```

Agora eu testei imaginando como o código fosse escrito em inglês e a variável ficasse igual a propriedade da própria Exception no caso "message", conseguiria sobrescrever (Override).

```
class SaldoInsuficienteException(override val  message :String = "O saldo é Insuficiente") : Exception()
```

Também funcionaria , mas não entendi o porque disso, e se contar pelo Override "val " que poderia ser " var " e mesmo assim funcionaria e poderia alterar a onde joga a Exception sendo val ou var . Porque isso?

Espero que me ajudem por favor !

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer o ***override*** em uma propriedade similarmente ao que é visto nos métodos em Kotlin. Cada propriedade declarada pode ser substituída por uma propriedade inicializada ou por uma propriedade com um método get.

Agora sobre val e var no ***override***, cuidado: você pode substituir uma propriedade val por uma propriedade var, mas não vice-versa. Isso é permitido porque uma propriedade val essencialmente declara um método *get* e substitui-lo (override) como um var apenas declara, adicionalmente, um método *set* na classe derivada.

Exemplo de código válido:

```
interface Shape {
    val vertexCount: Int
}

class Rectangle(override val vertexCount: Int = 4) : Shape // Sempre terá 4 vértices

class Polygon : Shape {
    override var vertexCount: Int = 0  // Pode ser mudado para qualquer valor depois
}
```

Você pode saber mais em: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#overriding-properties

Comment: Acho que a pergunta está relacionada com o facto de que a Excepção `SaldoInsuficienteException` funciona com as duas implementações e porquê. Pelo menos entendi a pregunta assim @BryandosSantos.

Comment: Expandi a minha resposta. Desta forma @Kainan pode ver um exemplo funcional e testar var e val.